# Error al enviar delete por ajax - Django Rest framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, djangorestframework, django-urls

Tengo 2 **serializers:**

```
class DetalleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    producto = serializers.CharField(source='producto.nombre')
    class Meta:
        model = DetalleVenta
        fields = ('cantidad','producto')

class PedidoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    detalleventa = DetalleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Venta
        fields = ('id','cliente','descripcion','detalleventa','atendido')
```

y mi **viewset**:

```
class PedidoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Venta.objects.exclude(atendido=True)
    serializer_class = PedidoSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            queryset = Venta.objects.exclude(atendito=True)
            object = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
            object.atendido = True
            object.save(update_fields=['atendido'])
            return Response({"status": True, "results": "Pedido atendido correctamente"})
        except NotFound as err:
            return Response({"status": False, "error_description": err.detail})
```

En el cual para el eliminar simplemente cambie el estado de mi campo **atendido** que es un booleano (true/false) una eliminación lógica.

y estas mis 2 **urls**:

```
url(r'^pedido/$',PedidoViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post': 'create'}),name='api-pedido',),
url(r'^pedido/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',PedidoViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update', 'delete': 'destroy'}),
        name='api-atendido',),
```

El recuperar todos los datos no hay problema, me trae todo lo necesario que necesito.

a través de la url: `url:  "{%  url 'api-pedido' %}",` **GET**

Pero cuando quiero hacer la eliminación lógica desde un boton **(DELETE)**:

**UDATE**
Corregí el problema de la url y es que tenia que enviarle de esta manera el **pk**:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "{%  url 'api-atendido' pk=85 %}",
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
      type: 'DELETE',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(result) {
         console.log('atendido correctamente');
      },
    });
 });
```

Como pueden observar en los header agregue el csrf de seguridad ya que django me obliga utilizarlo.

Ahora si elimina correctamente pero yo solo quiero eliminado lógico y esta fallando en la función **destroy** mostrandome el siguiente error:

[image: Imágen del error]

Es error en la función ya que si le quito esta funcionando correctamente.

Comment: En esta parte del codigo `url: "{%  url 'api-atendido' %}91",` que seria ese 91?

Comment: Es el identificador de una venta para probar si funcionaba lo puse en duro es como si pusiera: pedido/91

Comment: el parametro lo debes agregar en el ajax y no concatenarlo, data: { pk: 91} osea te quedaria url: {%  url 'api-atendido' %}, data: {pk:91},type:..

Comment: Gracias!! por la observación, sin embargo sigue sin funcionar, actualizo la pregunta con tu observación y otra captura de la parte de abajo del error.

Comment: `Venta.objects.exclude(atendito=True) ` influira el nombre (atendiTo)?

Comment: tienes mucha razón :D pero el problema fue el como mandaba los parametros en la url. de todas maneras gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto:
Primero los parámetros se envían de esta manera:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "{%  url 'api-atendido' pk=85 %}",
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
      type: 'DELETE',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(result) {
         console.log('atendido correctamente');
      },
    });
 });
```

Pide csrf por seguridad django y en su documentación dice que con jquery se implementa de esta forma:

```
// using jQuery
            function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }
```

y en mi funcion de **destroy** estaba como atendito y era atendido 
queryset = Venta.objects.exclude(atendido=True)

Con esto es suficiente para que funcione :) Espero le sirva a alguien.